# Selenium WebDriver(2.42.2) stopped working suddenly on firefox 32

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver

Webdriver on firefox has stopped working suddenly. Uptill now it was working absolutely fine.When I run my test I get a blank firefox page and then in the eclipse console i get the error. org.openqa.selenium.firefox.notconnectedexception.
I was using WD latest jar 2.42.2 with the firefox version 32. It was working fine till an hour back, and suddenly it has stopped working.please help. Snapshot of error is as follows-

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port     7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
```

Answer (score 4):

Firefox 32 is NOT officially supported by Selenium 2.42.2. See here : https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7836

We can expect sometime this week for 2.43 to release which will solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I need to upgrade selenium to version 2.43.1. Besides that I install the version 18 of guava.
It doesn't look to have relation, but it will work.

Answer (score 0):

A similar situation arose for recently me. Using 2.43 Selenium Python driver with Firefox v36 which was working perfectly for months on end, and used every day. Suddenly bang, not working. Firefox had updated to v37. To solve it all I did was update using selenium using: 
"pip install -U selenium"
Which installed 2.45.